# Clone/Backup of ArangoDB-Collection with Python

Tags: python-3.7, arangodb, pyarango

Is there a Pythonic way to do a quick backup or a copy of a collection (document and edge)?

The regular way seems to be using [arangodump/arangoimp](https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-training-center/using-arangodump-and-arangorestore-multi-database-installation/) in the console. Also there are some tutorials on how to do a full backup on a different server in JS.

I'm just trying a simple case: Directly copy a collection on the existing server.

Comment: Would it be OK to use an http API?

Comment: Technically the pyarango is also using the http API. So if it's somewhat implemented in pyarango, yes it's ok.

Comment: In that case, please check this API https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.5/http/export.html

Comment: So is it implemented in pyarango or not? That was my requirement

Comment: https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/pyArango/issues/43

Comment: I would also urge the use of the ["bulk"](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/document-working-with-documents.html#bulk-document-operations) interfaces for import and export.  They GREATLY improve speed, without the need to call an external program.